# Queue in multiprocessing blocked by threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, queue, multiprocessing

I need to transfer data from a subprocess to the main one.
The subprocess in doing a repetitive task using `threading.timer`
Whenever `threading.timer` is called, the `queue` does not work anymore.

The subprocess is acquiring data, while I want to display them in real-time in the main process.

I wrote this snippet to showcase the problem:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q
        print("put value in q: ", "start")
        self.q.put("start")
        self.i = 0
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if self.i < 3:
            print("put value in q: ", self.i)
            self.q.put(self.i)
            self.i += 1
            threading.Timer(0.5, self.update).start()
        else:
            self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        print("put value in q: ", "stop")
        self.q.put("stop")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target = MyClass, args=(q,))
    process.start()
    process.join()
    for i in range(5):
        print("get value in q: ",q.get(block = True, timeout = 2))
```

and I get this only:

```
put value in q:  start
put value in q:  0
put value in q:  1
put value in q:  2
put value in q:  stop
get value in q:  start
get value in q:  0
```

Is there a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `process`. It has main thread (`MyClass()` call). `threading.Timer()` spawns another thread along with main thread so you have to wait untill all additional threads are terminated before you stop `process`. So to solve the problem replace `threading.Timer(0.5, self.update).start()` with (wait for threads):

```
t = threading.Timer(0.5, self.update)
t.start()
t.join()
```

Or replace `threading.Timer(0.5, self.update).start()` with (no additional threads):

```
time.sleep(.5)
self.update()
```

Both solutions should work.

Comment: Yes they both work! Do you think it is a problem to use `t.join()` in a recursive function as the threads will "accumulate" until the last one is done? For three loops like here it's fine, but can I let it run for indeterminate time? is it safer to use `time.sleep()` in that case?

Comment: @RémiBaudoux It depends on the implementation details. Should note that your whole code looks complicated and convoluted to me. Creating class seems redundant. May be you should simplify the code? Like regular functions with loops.

Comment: Yes I have to simplify it, but it is the architecture of a 3000 lines project, and a lot of dependencies with the DAQ library, which makes it hard :)
Thank you for your help